# How to evaluate if there are any unfinished parallel task and wait for them to complete couple of sprints?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two tasks that cannot be completed until them both finishing couple of phases\sprints, while `task1` is little fast in finishing his phases and should wait before moving the next phase to `task2` to finish.

Is there a elegant way to allows notification of sprint completion to a parallel thread? without divide the `task1` and `task2` into many small tasks.

### To illustrate

Think of **Relay race** of two opponents, but with only one difference: each time the first opponent team moving the stick they wait for the other opponent team to move the stick and only then proceed.

### Example:

```
public static void task1() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 1");
    //Need to wait for task2 to complete sprint1 and proceed.
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 1");

    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 2");
    //Need to wait for task2 to complete sprint2 and proceed.
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 2");

    //etc... sprint N
}

public static void task2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 1");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 1");

    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 2");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 2");

    //etc... sprint N
}

//Main thread:
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Task1);
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(Task2);

//wait for task1 and task2 to be finished with waitAll(new[] {task1, task2})...
```

Comment: @Archer If I only make use of the `WaitAll` then `task1` sprint2 will begin immediately, and i want it to wait until `task2` end of sprint1.

Comment: I see now.  I think you need to break your tasks into smaller parts.  You can do what you're asking but it's much easier to just create smaller, more succinct tasks.

Comment: @Archer I see, I wanted to avoid diving the tasks to smaller ones, it is making the code harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: Maybe you should use continuation? =>  https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/dd270696%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If they're separate tasks then you should split them as separate tasks, rather than try to group some of them.  Personally, I think 4 different functions is clearer than 2 functions that run side-by-side, waiting on each other.

Comment: @Dahico Sorry but it still means that I will need for the entire task to complete.

Comment: @Archer thanks, but dividing them its not an option cause the number of sprints is dynamic.

Comment: They're still separate tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with using the `Barrier` class.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/barrier) definition:

> A barrier is a user-defined synchronization primitive that enables
>   multiple threads (known as participants) to work concurrently on an
>   algorithm in phases. ...

### Basic Usage:

```
static barrier = new Barrier(N, (sprint) => { Console.WriteLine($"Current sprint: {sprint.CurrentPhaseNumber}");
```

Then in each time we would like the fast task to wait for the slow task we just add:

```
barrier.SignalAndWait();
```

### Example:

```
static Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2, (bar) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Current sprint number: {bar.CurrentPhaseNumber}.");
});

public static void task1() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 1 (task1)");
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); //Need to wait for task2 to complete sprint1 and proceed.
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 1 (task1)");

    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 2 (task1)");
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); //Need to wait for task2 to complete sprint2 and proceed.
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 2 (task1)");
}

public static void task2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 1 (task2)");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    barrier.SignalAndWait();
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 1 (task2)");

    Console.WriteLine("Start of sprint 2 (task2)");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    barrier.SignalAndWait();
    Console.WriteLine("End of sprint 2 (task2)");   
}
```